# How Pandas groupby returns a boolean value by condition?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a dataframe assuming the date is `dd/mm/yyyy`.

```
person_id, date, dinner
1, 01/02/2019, pizza
1, 02/02/2019, pizza
1, 03/02/2019, pizza
1, 04/02/2019, pizza
2, 01/02/2019, burger
2, 02/02/2019, sushi
2, 03/02/2019, burger
2, 04/02/2019, pizza
3, 01/02/2019, burger
3, 02/02/2019, pizza
3, 03/02/2019, pizza
3, 04/02/2019, pizza
```

I want to get a new dataframe that consists of an id and a boolean value that shows they eat pizza 3 days in a row from yesterday. Let's assume that today is `05/02/2019`.

```
person_id, eat_pizza_3_days_in_row
1, True
2, False
3. True
```

What I tried is to filter the data, use group by function like this.

```
df = df.loc[(df['date'] <= str_yesterday) & (str_three_days_ago <= df['date'])].groupby('person_id')
```

but no idea what to do after grouping by. Is there any good way for this?

Comment: Will you always be looking for the last n days? (in this case the last 3 days?) Or is there a chance you may want any 3 days in a row of pizza out of say, 10 days of records?

Comment: @linamnt I want to looks for last N days! But it’s also nice to know a way to check any N days in a row if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you want to create a mask of eligible data, and then you can use `groupby().all`:

```
today=pd.to_datetime('05/02/2019', dayfirst=True)
mask = df['date'].between(today-pd.to_timedelta('3D'), today-pd.to_timedelta('1D'))

df['dinner'].eq('pizza')[mask].groupby(df['person_id']).all()
```

Output:

```
person_id
1     True
2    False
3     True
Name: dinner, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with `groupby.size` after using `loc` for the rows you want. Then check that the size is `eq` to 3 and `reset_index`.

```
today = pd.to_datetime('05/02/2019', dayfirst=True)
# loc where pizza and between today-1 day and today-3days
df_f = df.loc[df['dinner'].eq('pizza')
              & (df['date'] <= today-pd.Timedelta(days=1)) 
              & (today-pd.Timedelta(days=3) <= df['date']), :]\
         .groupby('person_id').size().eq(3)\
         .reset_index(name='eat_pizza_3_days_in_row')

print (df_f)
   person_id  eat_pizza_3_days_in_row
0          1                     True
1          2                    False
2          3                     True
```